# How to split a list into two in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, split, tuples

I'm trying to split a list into two so that when the input is

```
[1,2,3,5,6]
```

output would be

```
[1,2,3][5,6]
```

but I can't seem to figure it out.

The best I can do is `[1,3,6][2,5]`.

Comment: Could you post the code you've already written?  Without knowing what you're trying, it's impossible to point you in the right direction.  Also, could you define your function a bit more?  What if a different length list is inputted?  What are the conditions for splitting a list?

Comment: [Hoogle is your friend](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+%28[a]%2C+[a]%29)

Answer (score 10):

I am a beginner. So, please correct me if this is wrong or sub-optimal.

```
internalSplit :: [a] -> Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
split :: [a] -> [[a]]

internalSplit (first:rest) count firstPart
    | count == 0 = [firstPart, (first:rest)]
    | otherwise  = internalSplit rest (count - 1) (firstPart ++ [first])

split myList =
    let listLength = length myList
    in
        if listLength `mod` 2 == 0 then
            internalSplit myList (listLength `div` 2) []
        else
            internalSplit myList ((listLength `div` 2) + 1) []

main = do
        print $ split [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
        print $ split [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**Output**

```
[[1,2,3],[5,6]]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

**Edit:**

Managed to use builtin functions and came up with this

```
internalSplit :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
split :: [a] -> [[a]]

internalSplit myList splitLength = [(take splitLength myList), (drop splitLength myList)]

split myList =
    let listLength = length myList
    in
        if listLength `mod` 2 == 0 then
            internalSplit myList (listLength `div` 2)
        else
            internalSplit myList ((listLength `div` 2) + 1)

main = do
        print $ split [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
        print $ split [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**Output**

```
[[1,2,3],[5,6]]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

**Edit 1:**

```
internalSplit :: [a] -> Int -> ([a], [a])
split :: [a] -> ([a], [a])

internalSplit myList splitLength = splitAt splitLength myList

split myList =
    let listLength = length myList
    in
        if listLength `mod` 2 == 0 then
            internalSplit myList (listLength `div` 2)
        else
            internalSplit myList ((listLength `div` 2) + 1)

main = do
        print $ split [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
        print $ split [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**Output**

```
([1,2,3],[5,6])
([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

**Edit2**

As suggested by Bogdon in the comments section, this can be greatly simplified to this

```
split :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
split myList = splitAt (((length myList) + 1) `div` 2) myList
main = do
        print $ split [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
        print $ split [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**Output**

```
([1,2,3],[5,6])
([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

Comment: Why not use [``splitAt``](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) then? ``splitHalf l = splitAt ((length l + 1) `div` 2) l``

Comment: I used that in the second edit, but not as concise as yours. Thanks :)

Comment: @Bogdan Updated my answer with this solution.